# Finding the location of a particle given angular acceleration and linear acceleration

Tags: calculus, vectors, physics, kinematics

Given a rocket with known initial position, linear velocity, linear acceleration, orientation, angular velocity, and angular acceleration, and knowing that the linear acceleration will always be in the direction of the rocket's orientation, how would I find its position after time *t*?

I came up with the following equations:
$$
\theta(t)=\theta+\omega t+\frac{\alpha t^2}{2}
$$
$$
\vec{a(t)}=a*\hat{\theta(t)}
$$
$$
\vec{v(t)}=\vec{v}+\int_0^t\vec{a(x)}dx
$$
$$
\vec{r(t)}=\vec{r}+\int_0^t\vec{v(x)}dx
$$
However, calculating the Cartesian coordinates of the rocket proves to be extremely messy. Plugging the calculus into Wolfram Alpha yields an expression with Fresnel integrals when solving for x or y from taking the sine or cosine of the quadratic term in the  equation, which I have neither the experience nor the desire to deal with.

For calculating something like this, is there a simpler approach that I am missing? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this rocket confined to a plane? Otherwise you are going to need more than one parameter to denote orientation. Are both accelerations constant? Your calculations assume so, but you didn't say.  A constant angular acceleration is going to give you a very messy solution, no matter how you solve it. If that rocket has any passengers, they are going to have a very unpleasant ride.

Comment: The rocket confined to a plane, yes. Both accelerations are constant as well.